# Using custom components as router-link tag in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I'm trying to make the following Vue component work:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <cx-button href="/new">
            Create
        </cx-button>
        <router-link tag="cx-button" to="/new" class="cx-raised">Create</router-link>
    </div>              
</template>
<script>
    import cxButton from '../elements/cxButton/cxButton';

    export default {
        // ...
        components: {
            cxButton
        }
    }
</script>
```

But it throws: `[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <cx-button> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option. found in ---> <RouterLink>`.

Name of the button element is provided.

`cx-button` component is rendered fine by itself, same for `router-link` without using `cx-button` as value in `tag` property. The question is: what should I do to make `router-link` use custom elements, such as my button, as its tag?

Comment: You can wrap your custom component with the router link. 
I don't think you can force the router-link to render as a custom component, but only "classic" HTML tags.
`<router-link to="/new" class="cx-raised"><cx-button>Create</cx-button>/router-link>`

Comment: @reinarg, I was thinking that way until I stumbled upon Vue Material docs. It says I can use `<router-link tag="md-button">Router Link</router-link>` for their button, though I couldn't found how they've done it.

Comment: Oh you're right, I just tried  with a keen-ui component and the custom tag is working.
Can you provide a fiddle ?

Comment: @reinarg just made a fiddle with the similar code (https://jsfiddle.net/o_voloshin/a5jztd7s/3/) and it works fine. Seems like it's not about the `tag` property usage,  rather something with registering my custom component.

Comment: I have to say that the same situation appears for any working component I have in combination with `router-link`. Somehow it just does not know about those components.

Comment: I think it's because the component is used inside the router-link, so you need to register the component globally using Vue.use().
see it seems related :  https://forum-archive.vuejs.org/topic/2036/component-inside-component-unknown-custom-element-error-vueify/4

Comment: @reinarg it is as related as it possibly could be! Thank you for your help! I registered the component globally using `Vue.component()` and it works perfect.